# Android studio glide issue

Tags: android, android-glide

I have this line of code on my android studio app

```
if (obj.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
 ImageUtil.loadImage(GlideApp.with(context), obj.getPhotoUrl(), avatarImageView);
                }
```

**But it shows error "
Required type:
GlideRequests
Provided:
com.devlomi.fireapp.utils.glide.GlideRequests "**

This is my MyAppGLideModule class

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        registry.prepend(String.class, ByteBuffer.class, new Base64ModelLoaderFactory());
    }

   
}
```

How to correct the error I want to load images using the Glide

Comment: I don't see the mentioned line of code anywhere, can you provide full code of the necessary parts of your app ?

Comment: also describe what do you want to do as I didn't understand the flow of your app from what you said or what you expect your MyAppGlideModule to do ?

Comment: Thanks for looking into, @OmarShawky i have highlighted the first part of the code, that is where i get error

Comment: yes your class code doesn't contain that line so I wonder where do use it, furthermore please explain what you're aiming to do in your application, you did just mention that you get this error out of context.

Comment: show your `loadImage` method too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want is to load an image using Glide into an ImageView, then you don't need to extend any class inorder to use Glide.

you can just load the the image using its Uri with this line of code :

```
   Glide.with(context).load(obj.getPhotoUrl()).into(avatarImageView);
```

if that's not what you meant in your question, can you explain more ?

Comment: Yes, right, this is just what i needed, I am not that expert in java programming, I just needed to fix the error in my code as i am not the original developer, I didn't know how to explain it but it appears that the code was developed three years ago, and this answer solves the problem, i just needed to load the image from the url. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Glide Library it becomes a little easy to load the images from a url into an ImageView

And for this we use

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext).load.(obj.getPhotoUrl()).into(imageView)
```